# power bi embedded rest api share report

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to use power bi embedded service rest apis with a pro account, I have gone through the rest api reference guide -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi

The issue is that am unable to share a report with a particular set of users with the api, now i know that we can with rest api create appspaces/groups, and add users to group, but thats at the group level. I want to basically give permission at the report level. It is very easily possible from the app.powerbi.com portal by going into the share option. But there is no api that i can find to share a report to a user in an appspace.

We are stuck in our POC because of this as report level security is basic and a must have requirement for any kind of custom usage.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Power BI REST API doesn't allow you to do that. As you said, you can only manage users on workspace level. If you need such dynamic report level management, you can try to achieve this by removing the rights of your users on the workspace and embed the reports in some application, implementin "[app own data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers)" scenario. This way you will be able to manage user's access in your application, while the reports will be always accessed with your "master account".